# Reference to another object when reading but save with ID only

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a One-to-many relationship, as described below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some")
data class SomeEntity(
    val otherId: UUID,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val number: String = "12345",
) {
    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "other")
data class OtherEntity(
    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
)
```

I have no need to specify that they're @OneToMany or the @JoinColumn annotation.

With this structure, I can save a new OtherEntity, and after that I can save a new SomeEntity by passing the previously returned id

```
val ent1 = OtherEntity()
val savedEnt1 = otherRepository.save(ent1)

val ent2 = SomeEntity(savedEnt1.id, "123")
val savedEnt2 = someRepository.save(ent2)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to retrieve the OtherEntity object from the SomeEntity object.

```
val other: OtherEntity = ent2.other
```

If I just add the entire entity in the constructor, I must pass the entire `OtherEntity` every time I want to save a new `SomeEntity`

How do I just create a reference to `OtherEntity` without having it in the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve is defying the idea behind JPA. Which is to encapsulate the layer of persistent database storage and hide it so that you can work with JVM objects without the need of reflecting how should their data be organised for it to make sense in a relationship database.

As you probably know, an `@Entity` is one of the basic concepts of JPA. By implementing and annotating the reference of one `@Entity` to another, you let JPA understand what SQL statements it has to prepare ahead of time to use for your database queries, but also what constraints should it enforce on the tables and columns. This can't be computed on a flawed and simplistic assumption that a field `xyzId` must obviously be a reference to entity's `Xyz` primary key.

Moreover, the very code you'd like to achieve straight out points out you want your `SomeEntity` class to have a field `other: OtherEntity`, not `otherId: UUID`. But since one Entity has to be stored in another table than the other, per the principles of RDMS, this is why JPA is employed in the first place - to do heavy-lifting of having a field storing a foreign key to another table stored in one model, so that said key can be used to manually retrieve data from another table.

Take a step back and re-asses your assumptions. Remember that having a relationship defined between your `@Entity` classes doesn't necessarily imply constant over-fetching of data - as these related entities may be lazy-loaded on demand, if so desired.

Comment: I might have made some mistake in my example, but I've done it before in another project with Java.
Basically what I'm trying to achieve is not to have the need to always refer to the entire entity when I'm creating a new parent entity. 

Imagine i'm working with sql only:

`insert into other(id, other_column) values ('other_id', 'column_value');`
`insert into some(id, other_id, number) values('some_id', 'other_id', '12345');`

In the 2nd query, the ID of the `other` entity is the only information necessary to create the `some` entity.

Comment: Yes, I do realise what SQL statement will be necessary to introduce such a relationship to the database. Moreover, I assure you this is the kind of a statement that JPA will eventually use to store this relationship, as it is a framework designed to translate the Object-Oriented runtime environment, where objects refere to other object directly* to SQL environment where references are held by storying keys to other tables. I can help you enable SQL debugging so you can see what JPA actually does for you. Don't do its work for it.  *Not true on machine level but it is a common sense abstraction